# Does TcpInitialRTT value exist for Windows server 2012r2?

Tags: networking

I've some questions related to this parameter TcpInitialRTT.

1. Does this parameter TcpInitialRTT exist or name is changed in Windows server 2012r2?
2. I'm getting mixed information and being confused for example https://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-does-tcpinitialrtt-or-initialrto-affect-tcp-498 states TcpInitialRTT and InitialRto are same if so do you set TcpInitialRTT in registry and that would be output as InitialRto from PowerShell's Get-NetTCPSetting command?
3. Where can I find all the network related parameters that are supported in Windows server 2012r2, I've searched Google and not able to find the full list of network adapter/interface parameters that can be tuned for performance

The reason for my question is that here https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netro/2010/08/30/tcpip-stack-hardening-in-operating-systems-starting-with-windows-vista/ it states starting Vista they are no longer available so I'm assuming server 2012 came after Vista so it's applicable to 2012 as well?

4. If this parameter is not available in 2012 and say yet I set it here HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\interface\TcpInitialRTT what would happen? Would OS consider my set value or ignore?

Answer (score -1):

Since I didn't get any response from SF, I asked the same at technet and here's what I got for reference:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/00e3c024-51c4-4ba0-8502-29c18dc35539/does-this-parameter-tcpinitialrtt-exist-or-name-is-changed-in-windows-server-2012r2?forum=winserver8gen&prof=required